# How to get online users and their count?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to use this [package](https://github.com/shetabit/visitor) in my Laravel 8 projects for retrieving online users. However, I am lost. I follow the documentation but I don't understand the steps. When I login through another browser, it keeps giving me 0 users. What did I do wrong?

**User.php**

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait;
use Shetabit\Visitor\Traits\Visitor;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Visitor;
    use LaratrustUserTrait;
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

**DashboardController.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        $onlineUsers = $user->visits()->count();
        
        return view('dashboard.index', compact('onlineUsers'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`visitor()->onlineVisitors(User::class);` // returns collection of online users

`User::online()->get();` // another way

Comment: that's what in the document but  User::online()->get(); gives me an empty array

Comment: $onlineUsers = User::online()->get();